# sql server query - pivot after n columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, pivot-table, unpivot

I have a table with N Columns:

```
TABLE:
TB_SAMPLE

COLUMNS:

VALUE_A
COUNT_A
VALUE_B
COUNT_B
VALUE_C
COUNT_C
VALUE_D
COUNT_D
VALUE_E
COUNT_E
VALUE_F
COUNT_F
VALUE_G
COUNT_G
VALUE_H
COUNT_H
VALUE_I
COUNT_I
```

I would like to return like this:

```
'Value', 'Count'
A, 1 -- this is the first and the second column
B, 3 -- this is the third and the fourth column
C, 4 -- this is the fifth and sixth column
```

and so forward. I've tried multiple select's with UNION ALL clause, but as I'm returning a lot of records, it's not so fast. Is there a better way to 'pivot' this table 2 columns?

Thanks.

Comment: How the Count is calculated for each Column or value A?

Comment: Can you post some sample data from your table?  It is difficult to tell what the desired result is.

Comment: @techdo it's another app that save this information

Comment: @bluefeet for example I have 30 columns in a table. I would like to switch after every 2 columns. (First column and Second column in a row, third and the fourth in the second and so forward).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can also be performed using `CROSS APPLY` with a `VALUES` statement:

```
SELECT vals, counts
FROM temp t
CROSS APPLY 
(
    VALUES
        (value_a, count_a),
        (value_b, count_b),
        (value_c, count_c),
        (value_d, count_d),
        (value_e, count_e),
        (value_f, count_f),
        (value_g, count_g),
        (value_h, count_h)
) x (vals, counts);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1a7fc/6).

Here is an article to explain how this is done (registration required):

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/CROSS+APPLY+VALUES+UNPIVOT/91234/

Comment: Nice solution. Although, the link you posted requires registration which is a bit of a pain...

Answer (score 1):

You could UNPIVOT, then PIVOT the data, it might perform better:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE 
(   VALUE_A INT, COUNT_A INT, VALUE_B INT, COUNT_B INT, VALUE_C INT, COUNT_C INT, VALUE_D INT, COUNT_D INT, VALUE_E INT, 
    COUNT_E INT, VALUE_F INT, COUNT_F INT, VALUE_G INT, COUNT_G INT, VALUE_H INT, COUNT_H INT, VALUE_I INT, COUNT_I INT
);
INSERT @T VALUES (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1);

WITH D AS
(   SELECT  Category = SUBSTRING(B, 7, LEN(B)), [Type] = 'Value', A
    FROM    @T
            UNPIVOT 
            (   A
                FOR B IN ([VALUE_A], [VALUE_B], [VALUE_C], [VALUE_D], [VALUE_E], [VALUE_F], [VALUE_G], [VALUE_H], [VALUE_I])
            ) upvt
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  Category = SUBSTRING(B, 7, LEN(B)), [Type] = 'Count', A
    FROM    @T
            UNPIVOT 
            (   A
                FOR B IN ([COUNT_A], [COUNT_B], [COUNT_C], [COUNT_D], [COUNT_E], [COUNT_F], [COUNT_G], [COUNT_H], [COUNT_I])
            ) upvt
)
SELECT  *
FROM    D
        PIVOT
        (   SUM(A)
            FOR [Type] IN ([Value], [Count])
        ) pvt;
```

You could also do this dynamically if required by querying the system views for column names.

**ADDENDUM**

Just realised this could be achieved with a join rather than a UNION and PIVOT, I'd imagine the join would perform better as it removes the PIVOT operation. I'd still advise testing both though to see which works best with your data.

```
WITH Val AS
(   SELECT  Category = SUBSTRING(B, 7, LEN(B)), A
    FROM    @T
            UNPIVOT 
            (   A
                FOR B IN ([VALUE_A], [VALUE_B], [VALUE_C], [VALUE_D], [VALUE_E], [VALUE_F], [VALUE_G], [VALUE_H], [VALUE_I])
            ) upvt
), Co AS
(   SELECT  Category = SUBSTRING(B, 7, LEN(B)), A
    FROM    @T
            UNPIVOT 
            (   A
                FOR B IN ([COUNT_A], [COUNT_B], [COUNT_C], [COUNT_D], [COUNT_E], [COUNT_F], [COUNT_G], [COUNT_H], [COUNT_I])
            ) upvt
)
SELECT  val.Category,
        [Value] = val.A,
        [Count] = co.A
FROM    val
        INNER JOIN co
            ON co.Category = val.Category;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to do it (if I have understood your question correctly)

```
declare @table table
(
value_a varchar(10),
count_a int,
value_b varchar(10),
count_b int,
value_c varchar(10),
count_c int,
value_d varchar(10),
count_d int,
value_e varchar(10),
count_e int,
value_f varchar(10),
count_f int,
value_g varchar(10),
count_g int,
value_h varchar(10),
count_h int
)

Insert Into @table
Select  'value a',675,
        'value b',646,
        'value c',13,
        'value d',22,
        'value e',768,
        'value f',223,
        'value g',66,
        'value h',55


SELECT  vals,
        counts
FROM 
   (
    SELECT  *
   FROM @table
    ) p
UNPIVOT
   (vals FOR cols IN 
      ([value_a],[value_b],[value_c],[value_d], [value_e],[value_f],[value_g],[value_h])
)AS unpvtValues
Unpivot 
    (
        counts for counters in ([count_a],[count_b],[count_c], [count_d],[count_e],[count_f],[count_g],[count_h])
    ) as unpvtCounts
where Right(cols, 2) = right(counters, 2)
```

**EDIT**

If you want to use some dynamic SQL then you could use this option (This creates a proper table in your DB instead of using a table variable)

```
create  Table  dbo.TempTable
(
value_a varchar(10),
count_a int,
value_b varchar(10),
count_b int,
value_c varchar(10),
count_c int,
value_d varchar(10),
count_d int,
value_e varchar(10),
count_e int,
value_f varchar(10),
count_f int,
value_g varchar(10),
count_g int,
value_h varchar(10),
count_h int
)

Insert Into dbo.TempTable
Select  'value a',675,
        'value b',646,
        'value c',13,
        'value d',22,
        'value e',768,
        'value f',223,
        'value g',66,
        'value h',55


Declare @ValueCols varchar(max),
        @CountCols varchar(max),
        @sql varchar(max)


Select @ValueCols = Coalesce(@ValueCols + ', ','') + '[' + Column_Name +']'
From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
Where TABLE_NAME  = 'TempTable'
And COLUMN_NAME Like 'Value%'

Select @CountCols = Coalesce(@CountCols + ', ','') + '[' + Column_Name +']'
From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
Where TABLE_NAME  = 'TempTable'
And COLUMN_NAME Like 'Count%'


Set @sql = 'SELECT  vals,
        counts
FROM 
   (
    SELECT  *
   FROM dbo.TempTable
    ) p
    UNPIVOT
   (vals FOR cols IN 
      (' + @ValueCols +')
)AS unpvtValues
Unpivot 
    (
        counts for counters in (' + @CountCols + ')
    ) as unpvtCounts
where Right(cols, 2) = right(counters, 2)'


Execute (@sql)

drop table TempTable
```